# How to find which properties are different using lodash isEqual(object, other) method?

Tags: javascript, json, redis, lodash

I am using `redis` to store an object by stringifying and later parsing it. Since the object contained a date object, I had to use `reviver` function of `JSON.parse` to convert the `date` string to `Date` object again.

The problem I am facing is that, the object received from `JSON.parse` and the original object are coming as not equal when I compare them through `_.isEqual(object,other)` method of `lodash`.

However, if I print the content of both objects onto the console and compare them, the contents come as identical. Has anyone faced this issue?

Here is some part of code which I added for testing purpose ? It is json.stringify which is causing the issue. 
`

```
var k  = JSON.stringify(j);
    k = JSON.parse(k, function (key, value) {
                   if (key === 'creation' || key === 'lastAccessed') {
                        return new Date(value);
                      } else {
                        return value;
                      }
                });
console.log("Are j and k equal ? ", _.isEqual(j,k));
```

`

Here is the Value of j :

```
    { _jar:
   { store:
      { idx:
         { 'XXXXXXXX.XXX.com':
            { '/':
               { JSESSIONID:
                  { key: 'JSESSIONID',
                    value: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    path: '/',
                    creation: Tue May 19 2015 12:27:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
                    hostOnly: true,
                    domain: 'XXX.XXX.com',
                    lastAccessed: Tue May 19 2015 12:27:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) },
                 ABC:
                  { key: 'XXXXX',
                    value: '2015.1.0',
                    domain: 'XXXX.XXX.com',
                    path: '/',
                    creation: Tue May 19 2015 12:27:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
                    hostOnly: false,
                    lastAccessed: Tue May 19 2015 12:27:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) } } } } } } }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you included some sample objects that `isEqual()` is returning false on. For example, what do `j` and `k` look like right before caliling `isEqual()`?

Comment: Have updated the value of j in the question details.

Comment: Can you also show us the ending value of `k`?